# Why my Android emulator does not start?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't know why but the Android Emulator doesn't want to start. After the text ANDROID appears, without the 3 points, after a period it stops as it is ready to go, but each time starts again to load.

How can I see if returned an error, or my computer configuration is the fault?

Thanks.

More info:

I received the following warning:

```
WARN/SharedBufferStack(166): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=1, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
```

And application seems to be stuck here. The same warning appears for several times.

Comment: You sure you've waited long enough? It's pretty slow first time

Comment: Yes, last time I let him run more than one hour, and didn't start.

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a new emulator instance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing your own system.img or are you using the default one? If your own, perhaps it has a problem in it.

You might try selecting the "wipe user data" box to be sure nothing you've installed into the image is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. It takes much time to start up emulator (max 3min).
2. If you get some errors you'll see them in logcat.
3. Try to create new emulator instance.

Comment: What does point one even mean? Perhaps reword it to be clearer.